# Upgrade .NET framework: cannot reference MonoAndroid 10

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-6.0

I needed to update the WCF reference of my project. Something that is apparently no longer supported in .NET 2, even `svcutil` didn't work. I was basically told I needed to update my .NET framework. So I did.

Now I get the following error message:

> Error
> Project '..\Picking\Picking.csproj' targets 'net6.0-android;net6.0-ios'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v10.0'. Picking.Android

I tried looking for this issue, but couldn't find any conclusive solution.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. WCF is supported in .NET Framework since forever. It is not supported in .NET 6. There is this [project](https://github.com/corewcf/corewcf) which I haven't tried myself.

Comment: @PalleDue Basically, i couldn't update my WCF anymore, and everything basically pointed to "SVC Util which is used to generate the files no longer support .net 2.0". So I looked up how to upgrade my .net and did it. It worked, I managed to update my WCF reference, but the project now has issues because I updated to .net6.0

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It's all in the question. The confusing thing is you mention .NET framework, when apparently you are on the .NET Core variety.

Comment: *"I was basically told I needed to update my .NET framework."* If you were told to upgrade to .Net 6, (or told to stop using ".NET Framework", and use a newer .Net, based on .Net Core, which runs cross-platform), see [Upgrading a WCF service to .Net 6 with WCFCore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/). BUT If you were told to upgrade to "a newer .NET **Framework**", the final one of THOSE is [.Net Framework 4.8.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481). Released in 2022; no more "Framework"s except security updates, AFAIK.